# open UNC path with spaces in windows explorer with perl

Tags: windows, perl

Hello stackoverflowers,

i'm afraid i can't figure out how to open an UNC path with spaces within Windows Explorer in perl.
Purpose is, i want the user to put a file within the path. To make it more comfortable, the path should open in explorer automatically. Which it does for any local drives.

The UNC path that should open is: \\srvr1\mean space dir

My code so far:

```
use strict
use warnings

my $sourceDir = "\\\\srvr1\\mean space dir";
system("start $sourceDir");
```

Which gives the error: "Win can't access \\srvr1\mean." 
Ok, so i tried to quote the string:

```
my $sourceDir = "\\\\srvr1\\\"mean space dir\"";
```

Which lead to: "Win can't access \\srvr1\"mean space dir"."

Next thing i tried was:

```
my $sourceDir = q{"\\\srvr1\\mean space dir"}
```

Which lead to an cmd window being opened with the correct path within the title?!

Is maybe the system call itself wrong?
I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second form is correct, but then you have to account for the fact that the `start` command treats its first quoted argument as a window title. If you want to `start` a quoted path, you need to give a window title argument too (the empty string is fine).

Like so:

```
my $sourceDir = q{\\\\srvr1\\mean space dir};
system(qq{start "" "$sourceDir"});
```

Comment: working perfectly fine. I read about the window title and tried it, but not with the second form i guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of thing the array style system call is a good fit. You don't need to worry about quoting the path or escaping as much.

```
$path = '\\\\srvr1\mean space dir';
system('start', '', $path);
```

Quoting (or forgetting to quote) paths in system calls is a significant source of bugs where I've worked. A habit of doing it as above means you never need to worry about it.

Comment: This is even more convenient and, at least for me, better readable.